# Creating fake (test) data

Tags: debugging

Is there a module or part of devel module that will auto populate (with fake data) a Content Type a create a dozen or so nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you installed the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, there should be a submodule on the admin/modules page called **Devel generate**:

[image]

Enable it, and you should have some new menu entries in admin/config/development for generating fake conent, menus, terms, users, and vocabularies.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/introduction-unit-testing) from [lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com) explains exactly what you will need. You will need / can use the following modules;

- http://drupal.org/project/simpletest
  This module is a Drupal extension to the [Simpletest](http://simpletest.org/) project for general PHP unit testing. The Drupal module adds a wealth of tools and convenience for Drupal specific unit testing. For example, it has the ability to create new users and nodes, set configuration variables, and submit Drupal forms.
- http://drupal.org/project/simpletestauto 
  provides a system for running test suites automatically and reporting the results. The Simpletest automation is also capable of applying patches to Drupal code, and is thus an essential tool for vetting patches in the issue queue.
- http://drupal.org/project/simpletest_automator 
  extends the convenience of writing tests even further by allowing you to click through your site as it records your actions as a macro. This macro can then be used as the basis for a unit test that you can run automatically at a later time.

> What is unit testing
>
> Unit testing is the art and practice of taking a small portion of
>   code, a unit, and subjecting it to programmatic tests to prove its
>   correctness. The smallest units in PHP code are usually functions, and
>   the unit tests will run the functions with sets of controlled
>   parameters, and then make assertions about the return values of the
>   function, or about the state of the application before and after the
>   function has run. For example, if the function is designed to validate
>   email addresses, the unit tests would pass in known valid email
>   addresses and assert that they validate correctly. The tests would
>   also pass in a number of invalid email addresses as well and assert
>   that they do not validate.
>
> Why is unit testing useful?
>
> Writing unit tests helps produce higher quality code on many levels.
>
> The availability of tests helps detect the introduction of bugs
>   whenever the programmer adds new features or refactors the code. This
>   is called regression testing. Tests also serve as a source of
>   documentation about what code is really expected to do. The act of
>   writing the tests challenges the programmer to consider possible edge
>   cases and their consequences. Last but not least, the act of writing
>   tests encourages the programmer to write code in small chunks that can
>   be tested independently.

Comment: A good answer for a different question :)